# Is it possible to implement when a person scans the qr code he automatically logged into the account on the web site

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can this be done? if possible. I'll be glad if you can tell me.

I roughly understood how to create a qr code. But automatic registration via qr code don't know

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Need more information to give you a working response.

Are you scanning the code with your phone? If so, are you scanning with your own app (android or ios) or with a developed app on your web project?

Comment: a qr code is created on a website for a person. And after that, at any time, he can scan this qr code through a phone or tablet and he automatically logs in under his account.